# Why stop gaining xp in wow twink

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just found out about twinking. I have given it some thought thus the question follows:

What are the main reasons that would determine you to go twinking by stop gaining xp in WoW other than say owning bg's at your current lvl?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'owning battlegrounds at your current level'; BGs are segregated by level range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Own some non-twinks.** This is the main reason, since it's easy to set up the character and PvP alts can be played on and off. It's far easier to get into the upper echelons of power in a level bracket that is not the top one, you just have to stop leveling and get gear levelers would usually skip. Twinking is an easy ticket to dominating low and mid level battlegrounds, with your only equals being other twinks.

**2. Avoid the arms race.** Getting to max level means farming Best in Slot equipment for months, enjoying it for a while and then having it become outdated as the new patch rolls out. Stopping leveling at, say, 70, allows one to play with the content of that particular part of the game without having the rug constantly pulled under them.

**3. Experience old content.** For example, you want to enjoy Ulduar. As a level 85, raiding the place would be a very different experience compared to those who would try it at the usual level of 80. You could try doing it at level 80 without twinking, and you'd either use quest greens from WotLK (too weak) or from Cataclysm (too strong), not to mention you'd probably level up midway. If you're a purist, you'd want to freeze at 80 and do it with the gear players used back when the raid came out. There are entire communities dedicated to playing outdated expansions with only gear from those expansions, for both reasons 2 and 3.

Comment: `2. Avoid the arms race`: Aren't you really just moving the arms race to a lower level? You spend a few months farming BIS equipment and then... you're done. That's it. Now, that has a certain appeal, sure, but it's hardly 'avoiding' the situation of becoming gear capped.

Comment: It's subjective. You either enjoy the process of obtaining the gear or you just see the gear as a means to something else. Personally, I hated running in circles and just wanted to get good gear, using it to do interesting raids and participate in PvP without a handicap. Ended up moving to Guild Wars :)

Comment: hehe subjective indeed. However one could argue that because its old and lower level content, getting a pug with level 85's would be easier than say getting 24 other players to do 25man heroic DS. So in that sense, you are avoiding a long drawn out "arms race". Btw on your first point, that really only came into effect recently did it not? capped players weren't mixing with uncapped players until a recent change. Or is it capped players from all levels in the bracket can play against each other...

Comment: Yup, there were initially brackets for twinks only. I had forgotten about them, but they've been removed anyway (http://www.wowwiki.com/Twink). Regarding PuGs, that's why I mentioned the retro communities - there are players, you just need to locate them.